# mypy catches errors better with TypeVar than Union

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

**First Implementation**

```
from typing import Union

U = Union[int, str]

def max_1(var1: U, var2: U) -> U:
    return max(var1, var2)

print(max_1("foo", 1)) # mypy accept this, despite the fact that the type of var1 is str and the type of var2 is int
print(max_1(1, "foo"))
print(max_1(1, 2))
print(max_1("foo", "bar"))
```

**Second Implementation**

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

def max_2(var1: T, var2: T) -> T:
    return max(var1, var2)

print(max_2("foo", 1)) # mypy shows an error here
print(max_2(1, "foo"))
print(max_2(1, 2))
print(max_2("foo", "bar"))`
```

I would like to know how mypy detects this error, and what does this mean the error thrown:

`Value of type variable "T" of "max_2" cannot be "object"  [type-var]mypy`

What does it means this "object"?

Searched for explanations in WEB, but couldn't find much

Comment: In your first implementation, `max_1("foo", 1)` is perfectly valid: `"foo"` is an int or a str, and `1` is also an int or a str.  But the TypeVar in your second implementation is something entirely different from a Union; for both `"foo"` and `1` to be instances of `T` would imply that `T` is `object` (the nearest superclass of both int and str), which isn't one of the possibilities you've given for it.

Comment: thanks... I am testing some things and return soon